# npm ERR! Unsupported URL Type: npm:string-width@^4.2.0

Tags: npm, nvm

I have got problem with installation project from collegue in other computer.

```
PS C:\Users\cerno\git\iotian-cli\iotian-cli> nvm use 6.0.0
Now using node v6.0.0 (64-bit)
PS C:\Users\cerno\git\iotian-cli\iotian-cli> npm install --force
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@2.1.3: "Please update to latest v2.3 or v2.2"
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: The v1 package contains DANGEROUS / INSECURE binaries. Upgrade to safe fsevents v2
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.19045
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--force"
npm ERR! node v6.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6

npm ERR! Unsupported URL Type: npm:string-width@^4.2.0
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\cerno\git\iotian-cli\iotian-cli\npm-debug.log
```

i tryed mixing u version with nvm, but erors in `6.x.x` are similar and in `20.x.x` it can do but i can't use there npm start... it must be in `6.x.x` version

Answer (score 1):

maybe your project has some dependencies that must be manually installed.
for your specific instance try:

```
npm i string-width@6.1.0
```

check latest version of package `string-width` here [npm packages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-width).
if there is a new package version, change the 6.1.0 to the current package version.

Answer (score -1):

1. Install nvm running this command:
   `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash`
2. then Close terminal and re-open to let the changes work fine and use this command:
   `export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"`
   `[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"`
3. update `Node.js` with `nvm` with this command:
   `nvm install node`
4. set latest Version as default with this command:
   `nvm alias default node`
5. now you can update npm with this command:
   `npm install -g npm`